# Java - Open the console or terminal a game is running in

Tags: java, terminal, console

I am creating a complex game, because of this I use System.out.println(); a lot to test to see if something works or to see if something went wrong. To see these messages I have been going to the CMD or terminal and running it from there but I was wondering if there was an easier way. I thought of a couple ways and came up with running with a batch, but I have no idea how to make one, and another way was to put a button in game that opens the console that the game is running in. I don't even know if the second one is possible but I was wondering if there was a way! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: why don't you just write to log files?

Answer (score 1):

This is what logging frameworks are for.

Use sfl4j - http://www.slf4j.org/ - in your code to generate the log events, and choose a suitable backend for your purpose.  I would suggest using slf4j-simple which is easy to get started with and which easily can be sent to a file you can view in your favorite file viewer.

http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html